# Java MapStruct always convert boolean to false

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have 2 classes.

First:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Document("user")
public class UserDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private final String username;

    private final String email;

    private final String password;

    private final Set<RoleDto> roles;

    private final boolean active;
```

Second:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Value
public class UserDto {

    String id;

    String username;

    String email;

    String password;

    Set<RoleDto> roles;

    boolean active;
```

And my mapStruct interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserConverter {


    UserDocument toDocument(UserDto userDto);

    UserDto toDto(UserDocument userDocument);
```

MapStruct always converts my boolean active to false. Is it a problem with Lombok? It generates getter isActive() and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you set true still it converts false ?

Comment: Yes. If active in source is true MapStruct converts it to false

Comment: why you don't use @Setter ? and try to restart   your IDE sometimes that makes problem for mapstuct

Comment: UserDto must be immutable

Comment: Could you update your question with an example where you initialize those objects? Builder annotation probably has strange behaviour.

Comment: I use injection by constructor with the lombok annotation @AllArgsConstructor. I will check tomorrow if restart IDE will help.

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart IDE doesn't help

Comment: Can you please share the `UserConverterImpl`? I don't really understand what you mean with it always converts to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserConverter {


    UserDocument toDocument(UserDto userDto);

    UserDto toDto(UserDocument userDocument);
    
    @Condition
    default boolean active(String value) {
        return value != null && !value.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).